# Flat file or database for an android chat application

Tags: php, flat-file

Though answers might be opinion based but i felt SO is the right place to get my question and curiosity answered from expert in file manipulation as i'm still learning.

I'm building an android chat app and i have been worried about a good way to store chat messages (these messages will be deleted from the server immediately when they are delivered)

Currently, i'm using this approach to store the chat messages: Each single message has a separate file in recipient's folder and it's named after chat id like: 3271374.txt. Each message can only contain at most 10kb of data.

See structure below

```
/chats/RECIPIENT_USERNAME/
                 3271374.txt
                 4671368.txt
                 0681366.txt
                 message_ids.txt
```

message_ids.txt will contain chat ids of the messages only in this format (space separated ids) :

```
 3271374 4671366 0681366
```

To get messages, i will read ids in "message_ids.txt", explode it and foreach id i file_get_content("$id.txt") to fetch the messages and delete immediately.

This approach is actually doing well for me, in fact i sent and receive 1000 messages to a single recipient( just for test though, in the real sense there will only be maximum of 300 files(messages) in a recipients folder)

I'm storing each message in a separate file to avoid concurrency or data curruption while writing and reading messages.

1. Is my approach future proof
2. I did my test in local server, what should i expect when i move it to production server -shared host to be precise?
3. Do you have a better approach

I know database will solve concurrency issue but i want to avoid database issues and since the messages will not be there forever i want to avoid SELECT*FROM, DELETE, UPDATE for a single call each time because i may be forced to use the 3 in every single call to server.

Comment: You might still have issues updating `message_ids.txt` file, no? If possible I would use MySQL or PostgreSQL, or at least SQLite or even FlatDB or SleekDB (flat file DBs written in PHP). Using flat files is also OK for sure.

Comment: Actually  before i make use of or read message_ids.txt  i rename it, and renaming in php is atomic and remember that chat ids been appended in message_ids.txt is just 15bytes each so i feel there is lowest chance of  concurrency occuring..(Correct me if i'm wrong)...I will definitely check FlatDB & sleekDB

Comment: Yes, I would also suggest to rename or use `flock` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

Comment: ..I appreciate you..I'm currently looking into flatDB didn't know such existed. I will read about flock too.

Answer (score 0):

from the folder / files :

```
/chats/RECIPIENT_USERNAME/
             3271374.txt
             4671368.txt
             0681366.txt
             message_ids.txt

    message_ids.txt : 
    3271374 4671366 0681366
```

how about do a "file list" in “/chats/RECIPIENT_USERNAME/” and

get the "3271374.txt" without read / write from "message_ids.txt" ?

Comment: Nice idea but Could you please a good way to "file list"?

Comment: to get file list, you may check this 

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-php--cms-38044